# Magento 1.9 after installing patch the add to cart, customer login are not working?

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

Magento 1.9 after installing patch the add to cart, customer login is not working the list of patch that is installed was-

- PATCH_SUPEE-10415
- PATCH_SUPEE-10266
- PATCH_SUPEE-9767
- PATCH_SUPEE-9652
- PATCH_SUPEE-8788
- PATCH_SUPEE-7405
- PATCH_SUPEE-6788
- PATCH_SUPEE-6482
- PATCH_SUPEE-6283
- PATCH_SUPEE-5994

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of **form key**.
You need to add following line to add **form key** just after **form** tag in give file list

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
```

> 1) For Add to cart in product view
>   app/design/frontend/theme/package/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
>
> 2) For login & customer registration
>   app/design/frontend/theme/package/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml
>   app/design/frontend/theme/package/template/persistent/customer/form/registration.phtml
>
> 3) Update cart
>   app/design/frontend/theme/package/template/checkout/cart.phtml

I hope it will help you. Let me know If you still gets trouble

Thank You

Comment: Yes, it resolved the problem.....!

Comment: Glad to know it :) @govindaraj